# Unable to import example projects in eclipse from book

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to import projects into the Eclipse IDE from a book "Beginning Android 2" but when I choose the root directory the "Finish" button is still grayed out. I've tried importing the project from scratch with no success, and I've also tried to create a template project with the same name and everything and then importing into that (Import existing projects into workspace) but it always says "No projects are found to import".

The contents of the folder are: `Res` folder, `src` folder with `.java` file, the manifest, build, and `default.properties` files.

Comment: Are you using eclipse?  What dialog is the button grayed out at?  A screenshot would really help.

Comment: http://imgur.com/in5Aw.png //// 
http://imgur.com/LFwnh.png - This shows the option grayed out ////
http://imgur.com/izisK.png - these are the files in the folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Android project. In the new-project wizard, choose the "code from existing project" radio button. Click the Browse button and pick the downloaded project directory. This will fill in the rest of this page of the wizard. Accept all the rest of the wizard defaults, and your project will be set up. You may also need to tick the checkmark next to the Android JAR file in your build path.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much. I should have been able to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

If you copied/unzipped the Android project into your Eclipse workspace you can select

> Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace.

That worked for me when the "Existing Android Code into Workspace" didn't.  I was making a copy of a project so I could experiment without having to worry about version control or breaking something that was working.